# python logging close logger

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to close a logger in the sense that I Want it to be close and reopened when a new pbject is created:

```
import logging, logging.config

class myclass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        """ Initializes the main attributes of the parent class """
        logging.config.dictConfig({'version': 1, 'disable_existing_loggers': True})
        logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',
                            format='',
                            filemode='w',  # Overrides existing log file
                            level=logging.INFO)  # DO NOT RAISE LEVEL
        self.lgr = logging.getLogger('mylogger')
        self.lgr.info(f"data is {data}")
        self.data=data


a = myclass(data=1)
b = myclass(data=15)
```

`test.log` now contains:

```
data is 1
data is 15
```

I would have wanted to only contain 15, basically the file containing `data is 1` would have been overwritten.

Comment: `logging.shutdown` will close the file, but the doc says explicitly that you aren't supposed to use the logging module after you've done that.  Are you sure you want to use `logging` instead of just writing to the file normally?

Comment: `logging.basicConfig`: "This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument *force* is set to ``True``."

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that seems to be it, but not available on python 3.7. Lets see if I can upgrade...

Comment: @Samwise yes, in  my actual case the name of the file will be created dynamially. I could simply write to a file thats true, but I wanted to be a bit more pythonic ;)

Comment: If you want to write to a file, *use a file directly*. `logging` is for logging, that this often goes to a file is rather incidental.